# Framework 7 left panel background image issue

Tags: css, html-framework-7

I have set a background image for the side panel and using CSS I have blurred the image. The problem is that whatever I do to the image, the same happens to the text and icons in the side panel. So, all my text is blurred instead of just the image. I even tried to create a different class to hold the background image but same thing happens.

```
.background-image-holder {
background-image: url(../img/bg.jpg) !important;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
filter:blur(5px);
}

<div class=“panel panel-left panel-reveal background-image-holder”>
<div class=“list-block”>
<div class=“content-block-title”>Navigation</div>
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The div with list-block is within the same div that is being blurred. As the div "background-image-holder", is blur, any of its child would be impacted. You can create a separate div within the panel, but before/after list-block.

```
<div class=“panel panel-left panel-reveal”>
  <div class=“background-image-holder"></div>
  <div class=“list-block”></div>
</div>
```

Alternatively in pure css, is to create a before or after block for the div panel

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YQxMba